# Python runs old functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, quart, hypercorn

I have a project build with `PY3` with `Quart`.
I run it with `hypercorn`.
I have deployed a new version, but when I post a request I get old response.

I did a simple test, and wrote a static response in one of my routes to see the change. Nothing.
I have killed all my process and restarted them.
I have restarted the server. Noting.

Started the app with  `python3 app.py`, Same.
What am I missing?

Here is a code example:

app.py

```
__package__ = 'nini'

from .setups import create_app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', debug=True)
```

test.py

```
from quart import jsonify, app, current_app
from quart_openapi import PintBlueprint
from datetime import datetime


results = PintBlueprint('test', __name__)


@results.route('/test/test')
async def get_tests():
    t = get_float_t(get_user_t())
    return jsonify(t), 200
```

I have changed the function result of `get_user_t` function.
After deploy I looked and the code was changed but I keep getting the old result.
I cleaned all the **pycache** folders, build folders and egg files and run `sudo  pip3 install -e .`

To test what's heppening I changed `get_user_t` route to this:

```
@results.route('/test/test')
async def get_tests():
    t = get_float_t(get_user_t())
    return jsonify('9999'), 200
```

I still Get the old result.

Also cleared all

Comment: You need to make a [mre]. I don't know Quart or Hypercorn, but it seems like there's not enough detail here to find the problem.

Comment: You probably didn't deploy correctly.

Comment: Not a hypercorn user, but have you tried restarting it or cleaning \_\_pycache\_\_?

Comment: @ArthurKhazbs Actually I didn't. 
But now I did and still I get the same result.

Comment: @wjandrea I have added the code you asked for.

Also it doesn't matter if I run it with hypercorn or just `python3  app.py`.
The result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it was permissions problem.
For some reason the service was unable to create `__pycache__` folders and files.
It worked after I ran it as `root`.

I know it's not a good idea to run a service as root, so I will work out the permissions problem.

Comment: Instead of running something as `root`, you may try using `chmod` and/or `chown` to set up directory access permissions and ownership correctly.

Comment: Yes, sure... I know it.
Thing is that is already ran under the user that had permissions on the project dir.  That is why I didn't think permissions right away.
As this is a dev env I didn't want to waist any more time on this at this time. But I saw that others did have the same problem, and wanted to answer for future reference.